# Explode dataframe with string values without explode function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this
(Pandas version 0.23.4)

```
Emp   Factors         Comments        Action     ActionText
1   "['1','1']"  "["not","some"]"    "['1']"    "['good','as']"
2   "['1']"      "['textB']"          "[]"       "['da']"
```

I cannot use

```
df.set_index('Emp').apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index().drop('level_1', 1)
```

as it is not unique always.
PS: type of Factors, Comments, Action, ActionText are **String** in df.
**For any values of multiple entries ([,]) of the column, I want a new row in output DF.**
I want the output df be like

```
Emp Factors Comments Action   ActionText
1    1        not     1         good
1    1        some    1         as
2    1        textB   ""or nan  da
```

Comment: @AlexandreB. I'm assuming a typo, since everything else seems to line up

Comment: is your quoted text consitent? for example in comments your have "not" in row 1 and 'textB' in row2

Comment: hi @Datanovice I have editied the question, made a typo earlier, please check now.

Comment: @R.singh Why do you want to avoid using `explode`?

Comment: @a_guest maybe they don't want to avoid using it - they just can't upgrade to 0.25+ from 0.23.4...

Comment: I cannot upgrade the pandas version

Comment: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) has a few different ways to `unnest` or `explode` a dataframe

Answer (score 2):

#### `zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

data = [
    (emp, *tup)
    for emp, *other in df.itertuples(index=False)
    for tup in zip_longest(*other)
]

pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns)

   Emp Factors Comments Action ActionText
0    1       1      not      1       good
1    1       1     some   None         as
2    2       1    textB   None         da
```

---

#### Setup

What I assumed `df` to be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, ['1', '1'], ['not', 'some'], ['1'], ['good', 'as']],
    [2, ['1'], ['textB'], [], ['da']]
], columns=['Emp', 'Factors', 'Comments', 'Action', 'ActionText'])
```

Comment: Cannot hardcode e,f,c,a,t as the number of columns can varie

Comment: @R.singh I generalized it

Answer (score 1):

I had to fix `Comments` for `Emp` 1 into `"['not','some']"` in order to make it parseable. Then I used 2 utility functions: first one to convert the strings to lists, second one to process the rows of the original dataframe.

After my fix the dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Emp': [1, 2], 'Factors': ['"[\'1\',\'1\']"', '"[\'1\']"'],
                   'Comments': ['"[\'not\',\'some\']"', '"[\'textB\']"'],
                   'Action': ['"[\'1\']"', '"[]"'],
                   'ActionText': ['"[\'good\',\'as\']"', '"[\'da\']"']})
```

or

```
   Emp      Factors          Comments   Action       ActionText
0    1  "['1','1']"  "['not','some']"  "['1']"  "['good','as']"
1    2      "['1']"       "['textB']"     "[]"         "['da']"
```

My code is:

```
def do_eval(x):
    if not isinstance(x, str): return x
    while(isinstance(x, str)):
        x = ast.literal_eval(x)
    return x if len(x) > 1 else x[0] if len(x) == 1 else None

def make_df(row):
    d = row.apply(do_eval).to_dict()
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            return pd.DataFrame(d)
    return pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])

resul = pd.concat(df.apply(make_df, axis=1).values)
```

It gives:

```
   Emp Factors Comments Action ActionText
0    1       1      not      1       good
1    1       1     some      1         as
0    2       1    textB   None         da
```